# Getting Mobile Number through Https request in GPRS

Tags: php, http, https, gprs

Generally when we are using GPRS connection , the request will be sent to appropriate host as a http(s) request .  In receiving side ( PHP ) , we are able to get the IP address using $_SERVER or $_REQUEST variable  . Like that is there any way to get the mobile number that  means from which mobile number request being given. Can any one help me out of this problem....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** you cannot get the mobile number. Http does not know about the GSM client that is your mobile phone. Even the mobile does not have an IP, the IP you're getting is the IP of the GPRS gateway of the telecom service provider of the mobile SIM card.

Only way out is to **prompt the user to input his mobile number** and trust the user for he has given correct mobile number and get that mobile number from Http-GET or Http-POST at your server-side.

Comment: No not possible. This will never be possible over plain Http.

Comment: It is possible, but just not as a standard header, e.g. it differs from regions, see my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607540/getting-mobile-number-through-https-request-in-gprs/7738822#7738822

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You cant get any phone number information of any 3G or GPRS device. Cellular service provides not gives this data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the possibility to open a WAP page, you might get the MSISDN since it is included in the request header per default.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but there's no global standard, each operator uses their own standard depending on different things (software used, whitelists etc).

See this answer for more details:
[Can a mobile web application access the devices phone number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915852/can-a-mobile-web-application-access-the-devices-phone-number/7738711#7738711)